# Swift 3 updates that cause error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I updated to swift 3.0 and I get these two errors please help. Theres the code and images below

I get an error at self.blockfinish

```
var blockFinish: ((_ selectedTags: Array<Tag>, _ unSelectedTags: Array<Tag>) -> ())!

func finishTagController() {
    var selected: Array<Tag> = Array()
    var unSelected: Array<Tag> = Array()

    for currentTag in tags {
        if currentTag.isSelected {
            selected.append(currentTag)
        }
        else {
            unSelected.append(currentTag)
        }
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        self.blockFinish(selectedTags: selected, unSelectedTags: unSelected)
    })
}
```

Here I get an error at let ("addTagView.textEdit.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(spaceSet)")

```
func createNewTag() {
    let spaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
    let contentTag = addTagView.textEdit.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(spaceSet)
    if strlen(contentTag) > 0 {
        let newTag = Tag(isSelected: false, isLocked: false, textContent: contentTag)
        tags.insert(newTag, atIndex: tags.count)
        collectionTag.reloadData()            
    }
    cancelEditTag()
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1We9W.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You edited the question to delete one of your problems after I answered it and I undid that change. Don't delete questions after they have been answered because the whole point is to help others with this information as well. Also for the future, when the error messages are simple as the ones you have, just type or paste them into the actual question rather than pasting a screenshot link. Links can disappear and that information will be gone forever, not to mention the error will not be searchable.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to point out the problem, I'll change it back

Comment: Dina can you please help me, I'm sorry

Comment: what did you do, I'm confused if you fixed it or restoring the page. All I want to know is hot to fix it. Can you help me please

Comment: I undid your edit but kept the property declaration you added. Check my updated answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for the string trimming method has changed in Swift 3.0. [Here is the new method:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1643030-trimmingcharacters)

```
func trimmingCharacters(in set: CharacterSet) -> String
```

So instead of:

```
let contentTag = addTagView.textEdit.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(spaceSet)
```

you would do this:

```
let contentTag = addTagView.textEdit.text.trimmingCharacters(in: spaceSet)
```

**edit:**
`blockFinish` takes no parameter names at the call site.

Replace:

```
self.blockFinish(selectedTags: selected, unSelectedTags: unSelected)
```

With:

```
self.blockFinish(selected, unSelected)
```

Comment: what about the other error, could you help me with that, the blockfinish error

Comment: your right, but the block finish error is really making me struggle

Comment: can you please help

Comment: You need to provide the declaration for the `blockFinish` property. Something is mismatched but we can't tell you what without that information.